# My NanoPi-m1 board recognizes the USB mouse but not recognizes USB keyboard

Tags: usb, keyboard

I have an ARM-based board with Armbian(Ubuntu-server 16.04) installed on it. it recognizes my USB mouse but not recognizes my USB keyboard! I did reboot but nothing happened!

I also must to say my keyboard works and my board could recognize it last time with Ubuntu desktop

Comment: most problems with RPi or boards of the same construction come from too little voltage. And the problem is usually not the power supply but the USB cable. try using a thick cable. (From an external hard disk, for example)

Comment: Unfortunately the keyboards cable is built-in and can't change the cable.But I can remember I could use this keyboard before

Comment: No, I mean the voltage cable to the nanoPi. Most of the time, the problem is that the USB ports do not get enough power. So the power cable from the plug adapter to the NanoPi

Comment: @Joe6pack: thanks but didn't work!
I changed the power adapter with my SAMSUNG NOTE5 adapter that has fast charg with 9V ability but keyboards LED is on like before, but buttons don't work!